Gradient of softmax function with the inner product argument
Suppose that $x_i$ and $y_j$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$, where $i,j\in\{1,2,\dots,N\}$. Let the loss function be defined as $$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{N}\ln\left(\frac{\exp({\frac{x_i.y_i}{\tau\lVert x_i \rVert \lVert y_i \rVert })}}{\sum _{j=1}^N \exp({\frac{x_i.y_j}{\tau\lVert x_i \rVert \lVert y_j \rVert })}}\right),$$ where $.$ denotes the dot product and $\tau$ is a constant. The goal is to find the gradient $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_i}$. I tried to write the vectors in the component form but computing the gradient is really difficult in this form, even in the case $d = 2$ and $N = 2$ (mainly because there are multiple function compositions). How the gradient can be computed using the vector calculus? Maybe with the help of vector calculus the gradient can be computed more efficiently.

Which part of taking the derivatives is giving you trouble? The multiple function compositions are handled by the chain rule so you can just compute the derivative of each nested function then multiply them all together in the end

@whpowell96 The issue is that in the component form the expression for the derivative becomes large and it doesn't give any insight. I think using the vector calculus the derivative can be computed more clearly and efficiently but I'm not so familiar with it.

Haven't used this site but a quick look suggests it might be helpful:  https://www.matrixcalculus.org/

The first thing to do is in my opinion to write your loss function in vector form (with no index). The rest should follow easily.

@Steph Can you explain how that can be done, please? I couldn't write it in the vector form.

You can start by defining a vector, say $\mathbf{p}=\operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{a}/\tau)$ where $\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{Y}^T \mathbf{u}$, $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{x}/|\mathbf{x}|$.
